# Implicit and explicit SQL connection, which one mimic the onpremises connection inside connection string

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I know that in Power Platform you can connect to SQL in two different ways; using implicit and explicit. I know the security considerations of using implicit connector and that the connection will be available to any user to reuse it inside his/her power app.

So in our case we want to build a Power Automate and Power Apps to connect to SQL server on Azure. We are planning to use the explicit connection, but not sure how this will work on reality.

I came from SQL server on-premises, where accessing the database is restricted to certain users (mainly DB admin & the service account), but users interact with the database using a service account inside the connection string.

If we use explicit connection, then all users can access the database inside azure? So how we are going to secure our data? Let's say we only need certain users to view certain records inside SQL table?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the best of my knowledge

- Implicit connection to sql from PowerApps.
  This means you will directly use sql inside powerapps as connection. In this case the user who will be using/running Powerapps (in most cases you will be using canvas app here) will be authenticated/connected. If the user running powerapps does not have access to sql, powerapps will shout out and will not perfrom operations.
- Explicit connection to sql (in your case via power automate)
  Here we have 2 ways, run the power automate under the context of user who called the power automate (i.e user who is using power apps) or run the power automate under specific user (service account) even though powerapps is been used by normal user.

In case you use service account and this service account has access to sql, you will get desired results from sql.
In case you user normal user and connect to sql who does not have access. then no operation.

Additional, if you use power automate to fect data from sql or perfrom operation and you need to return large set of data back to powerapps, please check/keep in mind your return data size.